# SetFirstResult(0) works but not SetFirstResult(1)

Tags: nhibernate, detachedcriteria

I'm trying to do pagination on my webapp with MVC3 and nhibernate, the first page works fine but nothing else than `SetFirstResult(0)` works!

.SetFirstResult(request.pageIndex * request.pageSize).SetMaxResults(request.pageSize)

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=could not execute query
>
> InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>          Message=The column 'DossierN5_8_3_' was specified multiple times for 'query'.

I have searched a lot but I can't find anyone with the same problem.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have multiple column definitions. I'd look into that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I dont really now how to approach that.

Comment: Please post your NH query, as well as the underlying model and mapping. It will help understand why you tagged as "detachedcriteria", if you use a resultTransformer, if you use eager fetching.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SetFirstResult.
I found that the problem appear when I use JoinAlias.

Can't explain the reason, but after renaming alias everything is ok.

In my case problem was exactly with aliases and I guess in some cases changing join type to `JoinType.LeftOuterJoin` might help to.